# Generalization of the domain of the super logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, real-numbers

As you all likely know, one can get "intermediate" values of logarithms with the rules. So, I would say the "normal" logarithm is the logarithm where the outputs are non-negative integers, i.e. the input is of the form $b^k$ where $b$ is the base and $k$ is the output. Since the output will be an integer, we could define it recursively like so:

$\log(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 0 \; \text{if } x \leq 1 \\ 1 \; + \; \log(\frac{x}{10}) \; \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right\}$.

This is actually $\max(0, \lfloor \log(x) \rfloor)$, so it usually coincides with the regular logarithm.

Now, you might notice that this seems similar to the definition of the iterated logarithm
$\log^*$, which works like so:
$\log^*(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 0 \; \text{if } x \leq 1 \\ 1 \; + \; \log^*(\log(x)) \; \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right\}$.

I wonder how we could then take the iterated logarithm (and iterated iterated logarithm, etc.) and generalize them to outputs that might not be integers, i.e. replace their domain/codomain from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and turn it from a discontinuous many-to-one function into a continuous one-to-one function, effectively giving the super logarithm defined via recursion on the regular logarithm.

Also, what kinds of relationships might this function relate to other algebraic functions?

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: “Usually coincides with” is as an odd phrase for comparing two functions. There really isn’t a common mathematical definition for “coincides,” so it can mean whatever you want, but when you use words without definition, you should define them.

Comment: The integer logarithm of $x$ can be expressed as the small natural number $n$ such  that $\frac{x}{10^n}\leq 1.$ Since $1/10^y$ makes sense and is continuous and decreasing to $0$ for real we get the continuous logarithm as the value $y$ such that $x/10^y=1.$ Your question is much harder, repeated $\log$ does not have the same properties as repeated division by $10.$ Doesn’t mean it isn’t possible, but I wouldn’t be surprised if it was impossible to make it “nice,” like an analytic function.